# How I can hide labels on e_pie (Echarts4r)?

Tags: r, echarts

Hi and thanks for read me
I make a pie plot and I can to remove all the labels for the chart but I can't find a way to do this, anyone knows how I can do this? The code im using is the following:

```
mtcars |>
  head() |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  e_charts(model) |>
  e_pie(carb) |> 
  e_legend(FALSE)
```

I want to remove this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass further options to the `e_pie` function, including label options, as defined [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.label):

```r
library(echarts4r)
    
mtcars |>
  head() |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  e_charts(model) |>
  e_pie(carb, legend = FALSE, label = list(show=FALSE))
```

Or alternatively, you can also use the built-in functions where appropriate:

```r
mtcars |>
  head() |>
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  e_charts(model) |>
  e_pie(carb) |>
  e_legend(show = FALSE) |>
  e_labels(show = FALSE)
```